# Problems implementing antiforgery token in Angular 15 with NET 6 API

Tags: angular, .net-6.0, csrf

I already went through a lot of posts here on how to do this but nothing that works so far.

I used this piece of code in my startup.cs:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
{

    app.UseCors("AllowAllHeaders");


    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
    var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
    context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions()
    {
        Path = "/",
        HttpOnly = false,
        Secure = true,
        SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict
    });
    return next(context);
   });
}
```

And on the client in app.module.ts I added on the imports section:

```
HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
        cookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        headerName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'
    })
```

I do receive the set cookie header in every response from my backend, actually I receive two:

- .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Ls0lTb4JLpY=TOKEN;path=/; samesite=strict; httponly
- XSRF-TOKEN=TOKEN; domain=localhost; path=/; samesite=strict; httponly

But I don't see it saved on the developer tools of the browser under cookies or if I try to retrieve it in the javascript manually I receive an empty string:

```
const token = this.cookieService.get('XSRF-TOKEN');
```

Maybe also something that might help is that right now I'm running the app in my localhost and have different ports for the client and API.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are specific to the host+port combination generally, so your client and API need to run under the same port (or rather, have a proxy to achieve that) to be able to set and read cookies that way.

Also, you will never be able to access these cookies with javascript since they are set to httponly. You can view them in the browser dev console though.